# vbscript <%= %> always renders with extra space

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

Consider the following code in a .asp page:

```
DIM Valu
Valu = "10"
%>
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('[<%=Valu%>]');
</script>
```

Produces [10 ] in the alert.  Of course, this is a contrived example, but this addition of an extra space has bit me a number of times.  The following code gets rid of the space.

```
DIM Valu
Valu = "10"
%>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var v = '<%=Valu%>'; v = v.trim();
alert('['+v+']');
</script>
```

Why is there a space after the VBScript -> javascript converted value?

Comment: Seems strange, and even stranger that you're trimming a number without any errors ?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to quote my string.  I will correct.

Comment: In the vbscript, try `response.write "|" & Valu & "|"` - then you will be able to see if you are somehow starting with a space there.  I have never seen a space added by using `<%=something%>`

Comment: Strange that it's working at all; `DIM Valu = 10` should be throwing a VBScript error.

Comment: It is a mocked-up piece of code, I will correct the glaring error.